# Wordpress on IIS 7

Tags: iis-7, wordpress

What will be your preferred way of installing and configuring Wordpress on IIS 7.

1. Would you prefer using WPI (Web Platform Installer)?
2. Would you prefer manual download, install and configure PHP, mySQL and Wordpress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends, if you want a quick way to install PHP, SQL and Wordpress, use the WPI, its fast and easy.

If you want to learn how to setup these things manually, do them manually.

There is no reason not to use the WPI if you want things setup quickly and easily.

Comment: I agree, the reason why I ask this question is I want to know general perceptions on using WPI v/s Manual Installation. Is it just fast and easy installation or automated configuration feature and all in one platform for installing multiple applications from Microsoft as well as Open Source.

Comment: I'd be curious as to the type of admin that doesn't want a fast, easy, working install.

Answer (score 1):

Web Platform Installer makes it ***so*** easy to get all the pieces you need properly installed and configured that I can't imagine ever doing it manually again... Heck, even pretty Permalinks work right out of the box.

If I couldn't use WPI I'd probably resort to something like XAMPP instead of attempting your option 2.

Comment: Very True!. Not sure how XAMPP works but WPI will make life easy and hassle free.

Comment: xampp gives you an all-in-one install of apache / mysql / php. Not a bad option for dev, but would never go live with it: http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend Web Platform Installer it is easy to install wordpress on IIS 7. Just few clicks and your wordpress blog is ready. Manually would take time in configuration and everything.